# Content-Disposition is making pdf's that will not not open because they are damaged

Tags: php, forms, pdf, content-disposition

My Content-Disposition is making pdf's that will not not open because they are damaged. is there something wrong with my code causing this?

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="download"');
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contentdisposition.php" >
Job #: <input type="text" name="jobnum">
<br>
Program: <input type="text" name="program"><br />
Ship Date: <input type="text" name="shipdate"><br />
Description: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="description"><br /><br />
Proto Verified By: <input type="text" name="name"><br /><br />
Additional Notes: <input type="text" style="height:100px; width:85%" name="description"><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: save the pdf to puter, open with text editor, check for error messages at the top

Comment: is original.pdf in the same directory as the php file?

Comment: I dont have an original.pdf... I want to output the form data to a pdf. so when the user fills in the data they can save a pdf copy on their end.

Comment: then you have to build a pdf file, where did you expect it was going to come from in this code? It's programming not magic :-)

Comment: im noob >.< so I guess that part just flew over my head...

Comment: is there a way I can also get the data to output a html copy that can be edited by the user?

Comment: http://www.tcpdf.org/ that is what I and most of us use to created pdf's via php\html

Comment: html copy - sure, edited by user? that's what the form is for ?

Comment: for an intranet database.. basically there is an artist that will be filling this form out, than will save a pdf version and a html version  the pdf gets emailed to the printer while the html version sits on a server for later editing. hopefully creating a paperless workflow.

Comment: completely doable, but you need to put somework in to achieve it, its not really a question at this stage, just a project outline.

Comment: yeah i think i can handle it from here... THANKS!!!